# json encode - special characters

Tags: php, html, json, encoding, special-characters

I am using the json_encode function in a fairly simple quote system I have:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
postQuote[<?php echo json_encode($post['post_id']); ?>] = <?php echo json_encode($post['post_text']); ?>
</script>
```

Which outputs this:

```
postQuote["11241"] = "&amp;Kappa;&amp;alpha;&amp;lambda;&amp;eta;&amp;sigma;&amp;pi;\u03ad&amp;rho;&amp;alpha; &amp;alpha;&amp;lambda;\u03ac&amp;nu;&amp;iota;&amp;alpha; &amp;mu;&amp;omicron;&amp;upsilon;. \u0388&amp;chi;&amp;omega; &amp;kappa;\u03ac&amp;pi;&amp;omicron;&amp;iota;&amp;epsilon;&amp;sigmaf; &amp;alpha;&amp;pi;&amp;omicron;&amp;rho;\u03af&amp;epsilon;&amp;sigmaf;. \r\n1&amp;omicron;&amp;nu;: &amp;Eta; &amp;pi;&amp;rho;\u03ac&amp;sigma;&amp;iota;&amp;nu;&amp;epsilon;&amp;sigmaf; &amp;delta;&amp;iota;&amp;alpha;&amp;phi;&amp;eta;&amp;mu;\u03af&amp;sigma;&amp;epsilon;&amp;iota;&amp;sigmaf; &amp;mu;&amp;omicron;&amp;upsilon; &amp;delta;\u03af&amp;nu;&amp;omicron;&amp;upsilon;&amp;nu; $0.01; &amp;Alpha;&amp;nu; &amp;nu;&amp;alpha;&amp;iota; &amp;tau;\u03cc&amp;tau;&amp;epsilon; &amp;mu;\u03ac&amp;lambda;&amp;lambda;&amp;omicron;&amp;nu; \u03ad&amp;chi;&amp;omega; &amp;pi;&amp;rho;\u03cc&amp;beta;&amp;lambda;&amp;eta;&amp;mu;&amp;alpha; &amp;gamma;&amp;iota;&amp;alpha;&amp;tau;\u03af &amp;epsilon;\u03af&amp;chi;&amp;alpha; $0.60 &amp;pi;\u03ac&amp;tau;&amp;eta;&amp;sigma;&amp;alpha; &amp;kappa;&amp;alpha;&amp;iota; &amp;tau;&amp;eta;&amp;sigmaf; 4 &amp;pi;&amp;rho;\u03ac&amp;sigma;&amp;iota;&amp;nu;&amp;epsilon;&amp;sigmaf; &amp;kappa;&amp;alpha;&amp;iota; &amp;pi;\u03ae&amp;gamma;&amp;alpha; &amp;mu;\u03cc&amp;nu;&amp;omicron; $0.062.\r\n2&amp;omicron;&amp;nu;: \u03ad&amp;chi;&amp;omega; 5 rented ref. &amp;Tau;\u03ce&amp;rho;&amp;alpha; &amp;mu;&amp;pi;&amp;omicron;&amp;rho;\u03ce &amp;nu;&amp;alpha; &amp;alpha;&amp;gamma;&amp;omicron;&amp;rho;\u03ac&amp;sigma;&amp;omega; \u03ac&amp;lambda;&amp;lambda;&amp;omicron;&amp;upsilon;&amp;sigmaf; 3 &amp;mu;&amp;epsilon; $0.6 &amp;lambda;\u03ad&amp;tau;&amp;epsilon; &amp;nu;&amp;alpha; &amp;tau;&amp;omicron;&amp;upsilon;&amp;sigmaf; &amp;alpha;&amp;gamma;&amp;omicron;&amp;rho;\u03ac&amp;sigma;&amp;omega; &amp;eta; &amp;nu;&amp;alpha; &amp;pi;\u03ac&amp;omega; $1 &amp;kappa;&amp;alpha;&amp;iota; &amp;nu;&amp;alpha; &amp;pi;\u03ac&amp;rho;&amp;omega; \u03ac&amp;lambda;&amp;lambda;&amp;omicron;&amp;upsilon;&amp;sigmaf; 5;\r\n\r\n&amp;Alpha;&amp;upsilon;&amp;tau;\u03ac &amp;pi;&amp;rho;&amp;omicron;&amp;sigmaf; &amp;tau;&amp;omicron; &amp;pi;&amp;alpha;&amp;rho;\u03cc&amp;nu;."
```

The above text is (Greek):

```
Καλησπέρα αλάνια μου. Έχω κάποιες απορίες. 
1ον: Η πράσινες διαφημίσεις μου δίνουν $0.01; Αν ναι τότε μάλλον έχω πρόβλημα γιατί είχα $0.60 πάτησα και της 4 πράσινες και πήγα μόνο $0.062.
2ον: έχω 5 rented ref. Τώρα μπορώ να αγοράσω άλλους 3 με $0.6 λέτε να τους αγοράσω η να πάω $1 και να πάρω άλλους 5;

Αυτά προς το παρόν.
```

Now, to my understanding it encodes the string to HTML characters, Therefore before I output it, I do:

```
$(".quote").click(function() {
    $("#text").val($("<div>").html("[quote]" + postQuote[$(this).attr('name')] + "[/quote]").text());
});
```

Which doesn't help. The output is still the same as above.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
$s = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT t.*, c.forum_name,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id=t.topic_id AND post_deleted=0) as posts
    FROM forum_topics t
    JOIN forum_cats c on c.forum_id = t.forum_id
    WHERE t.topic_id=:id
    ");
$s->bindParam(':id', $id);
$s->execute();
$q = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while ($post = $p->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

//Postquote inside here.
}
```

My table `forum_posts` is `utf8_general_ci`

2nd edit:

It seems like a problem with GREEK letters? Any suggestions?

Comment: `json_encode()` works on an utf8 string, so your output seems unlikely. How are you filling your `$post` variable and can you do a `var_dump($post);`?

Comment: @jeroen please see my updated question. I have included the PHP.

Comment: You need to narrow down where the problem is. It appears you are using `htmlentities()` somewhere.

Comment: @jeroen not when selecting the text.

Comment: So perhaps before you store it in the database? What does the database contain exactly?

Comment: @jeroen in the database, the text looks like this: "&Gamma;&epsilon;&iota;&alpha; &sigma;&alpha;&sigmaf; &epsilon;&iota;&mu;&alpha;&iota; &kappa;&alpha;&iota; &epsilon;&gamma;&omega; " - but if it doesn't, how will I support foreign characters? Shouldn't the html() function convert it to HTML characters

Comment: You should use utf8 for everything, then you don't need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use htmlspecialchars(). This with proper options will make your string to be valid HTML.
json_encode is to get json string from PHP value. You are using this with strings, so in fact you will not want to have json. Particularly I don't see why you use it with post_id.